# Strange output of correlation matrix in "factor-analyzer" lib

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, factor-analysis

I'm trying to use factor analysis in some app and tried to compare 2 libs - "factor-analyzer" and "sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis". Wrote that method ("pd" in it is pandas, "df" - pandas dataframe and "delm" is html delimeter - br+hr tags):

```
def make_analysis(df, nf):

    fa1 = FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=nf, rotation="varimax")
    fa2 = FactorAnalysis(n_components=nf, rotation="varimax")
    fa1.fit(df)
    fa2.fit(df) 

    res1 = fa1.transform(df)  

    res2 = fa2.transform(df) 
 
    resdf1 = pd.DataFrame(res1) 
    resdf2 = pd.DataFrame(res2) 

    corr1 = resdf1.corr().to_html() 

    corr2 = resdf2.corr().to_html()  

    html = resdf1.to_html() + delm + corr1 + delm + resdf2.to_html() + delm + corr2 
 

    return html
```

[there are outpuning correlation matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SazoV.png). We can see that second matrix is almost diagonal and first is not. Does really lib "factor-analyzer" work incorrect with orthogonality or I should look other matrices? Pretty sure, such popular lib can't have an errors in such basics , but why second matrix is always almost diagonal and first is not and how to calculate correlation matrices of factors correctly?

Comment: Conceptual questions about ML/stats algos are better suited for [stats.se] or [datascience.se]. In the meantime, notice PCA (and factor analysis) [doesn't guarantee](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/526582/pca-leads-to-some-highly-correlated-principal-components) components (and factors) are necessarily uncorrelated

Comment: Thanks for an answer! So calculating correlations on original dataframe objects is correct? Why in this case there is such a difference between two libs, does this mean one of them doesn't work correctly with it?

Comment: I suspect these 2 just use different algos to arrive at their recommendations, without making any claims about their [in]correctness.